# How can you display the logs of only one of the replicas of a certain docker service without including its name?

Tags: docker, logging, service

I created a service called engineering-bay which produces realtime logs like this, constantly:

```
engineering-bay.1.xrva4xxj0kyd@Aiur    |  Zerg #153-14 from Hatchery c55ecf7dada7 : Bwaaaaarghfnle (I'm attacking this building!)
```

As I have two replicas, the logs also include these messages:

```
engineering-bay.2.yimbzwrkbf42@Char    |  Zerg #336-07 from Hatchery a810e3f2859e : Bwaaaaarghfnle (I'm attacking this building!)
```

My assignment is to "Get the real-time logs of one the tasks of the engineering-bay service". I have gotten as far as this command:

```
docker service logs -f $(docker service ps -f "name=engineering-bay.1" -q engineering-bay)
```

This gives me the output I need but I would like my command to not include the literal name of the replica. I'm not sure if it's possible but if anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know!

Comment: Do you mean that you don't care which one of the replicas you're getting your logs from (as long as you get them from a single one)? Or does it have to be the "first" replica?

Comment: do you use docker-compose to start your services? If so you can also use it to see the logs.

Comment: @NicolasB It doesn't matter which one! The assignment is just to display the task of only one of the services.

Comment: @Mihai I don't, I use docker service create

Comment: Why not something like `docker service logs -f $(docker service ps -q engineering-bay | head -n 1)` or something similar?

Comment: @NicolasB ahhh yes that actually solves it, thanks!